# Complete Quadrotor Tutorial (Text)Book?

Tags: quadcopter

I'm looking for a complete tutorial textbook for how to build and control a quadrotor (dynamics, control, etc.).

I'm an engineer with a broad background in programming, mechanics, and control but it's been several years and I'm rusty. I was just wondering if anyone knew of a great "from the ground up" tutorial for quadrotors? I found [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071822283) book which looks interesting but thought I'd ask here too.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

So, assume I've taken a formal course on all necessary topics: system modeling, mechanics, control theory, state estimation, programming, etc.

I'm looking for a book that assumes the reader is familiar with the topics but also goes step-by-step. For example, instead of just stating "here are the system equations" I'm looking for "let's derive the system equations" (but assumes you are familiar with modeling/kinematics). I'd like to start a quadcopter as a side project but have precious spare time so I'd prefer a single good reference instead of jumping from each individual topic textbook; maybe I'm just being greedy :)

Comment: You need to narrow the question a bit more. Quadrotor is a very complicated system. I don't think that a single book will be able to cover every single aspect in designing quadrotor.

Comment: @CroCo Updated the question with what I'm looking for.

Comment: I voted to close this question because, "Life Questions are off-topic. Questions about choosing how to spend your time (**what book to read**, which class to take, what robotics project to construct, what career to pursue, etc.) may be about difficult decisions, and they are often important, but they are too specific to your own situation and are unlikely to help future visitors to the site. They would be better off asked in Robotics Chat."